# RABL collection date format

Tags: rabl

I Want to return the datetime of the `updated_at` attribute in another format, but, in a collection.

If it was a single object, I'll do something like

```
object @person
  attributes :name, :phone
  node(:updated_at){|person|(person.created_on.strftime(%d,%m,%Y)}
end
```

But, how can I do that in a people collection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rabl file you shown being your `people/show.json.rabl`, you can declare `people/index.json.rabl` as

```
collection @people
extends "people/show"
```

This may solve you problem.